# Shared data in UITabViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I want all my sub views of a TabBarController to have access to the same information.

I have a Navigation Controller that lets a user select a row. When that is selected, it pushes a `NSMutableDictionary` to the first ViewController in the TabBarController. See screenshot for layout.

That works fine, but how do I get the other views access to that same piece of info?

The dictionary contains a lot of info and I want to break it off into other screens.

[image]

**From my UINavigationController**

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    UITabBarController *tbc = (UITabBarController*)segue.destinationViewController;
    CallDetailViewController *dv = [tbc childViewControllers][0];
    dv.thisDictionary = Some dictionary;

}
```

**Over at my first UIViewController in my Tab**

```
@interface CallDetailViewController : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSMutableDictionary* thisDictionary;
@end
```

*Do I need a `NSMutableDictionary` on every UIViewController? Or can I call some master dictionary file?*

It might be worth noting, I am not currently using a UITabViewController file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just put your dictionary property in your TabBarController so it can be accessible to all childViewControllers, the simplest way to do it, is subclass UITabBarController, and access its properties from each childViewControllers:

```
[(MyTabBarController *)self.tabBarController thisDictionary];
```

Also it helps to manipulate this dictionary from all of the childViewControllers